# How to configure different 404 page for each store in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4

I have two different store in magento. I need to create two different 404 pages with different content and assign it to different stores in magento 2.

How can i achieve this in magento 2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it from admin.

Create different page (Content  < Pages < Create page and set store in Page in websites store area)

Assign created 404 pages for stores in Admin < Stores < Configuration < General < Web < Default pages ( CMS No Route Page)
Make sure to select proper store in Admin Scope.

[image]

[image]